# Vetor Dinâmico + Alocação Dinâmica

Tags: c, array

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber como criar um vetor dinâmico em C, para armazenar as seguintes informações:

**estado_da_máquina(ligada, desligada,quebrada) | tempo_total_estado**

para exibir na tela, como se fosse uma tabela. 
Ex:  ligada | 120.000000 seg
     parada | 230.000000 seg

E depois contar tudo para exibir o total de estados.

Não sei nem por onde começar, e quero tentar fazer.
Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi qual é a relação disso que você quer (estado da máquina e tempo nos estados) com coisas referentes a vetores e alocação dinâmica. Me parece que você simplesmente está pensando em um tipo de solução que pouca ou nenhuma relação tem com o seu problema, e por isso você não chega a lugar nenhum. O que você está pedindo é algo mais ou menos de "**como empilhar tijolos para poder fazer suco de melancia?**", uma pergunta que nem sentido tem.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi o que você quer fazer certo, sugiro utilizar `struct`.

Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
struct meuVetorDinamico {
    char estado[20];
    float tempoEstado;
    float tempoTotal;
} algumAliasAqui;
```